# Can I Upgrade Windows 10 Enterprise 1511 Without A Server?

Tags: windows-10

My company went bust but I still have a laptop with Windows 10 1511 (`Enterprise 10.0.10586`) on it.

I turned it on today and it tried and failed to update Windows 10.

I tried to update via the 1809 iso (by double clicking it to mount it and then running setup.exe) but it also failed.

When starting it says:

```
To recap, you've chosen to:
Install Windows 10 Enterprise
Keep personal files and apps
```

It then runs for about 90 mins, gets to 94% and says

```
Your PC will restart in a few moments.
```

Then I am presented with the dialog box saying it has failed.

[image: Windows 10 Update Failed]

When I tried to update via the 1607 iso it asked for my product key but didn't recognise it as valid.

I suspect because it was a volume key.

Since none of the company servers exist any more and I am now logged in using a local admin account instead of a domain account, is it possible to upgrade to a newer version of Windows 10 (without buying a new licence)?

Comment: When you say you tried by iso, do you mean you tried booting from a disc? You can’t upgrade from a boot disc so I have to question what you actually did and what failed. Have you tried just running setup.exe in Windows? WHAT error exactly are you seeing?

Comment: Updated question with info requested

Comment: If it was a company system, it could be a KMS system, with a KMS/GVLK key. In which case you don't have a licence *now* and what you have *should* expire inm 180 days. It could be a digital entitlement, which does last forever too though - in which case you need no key. what happens when you run `slmgr /xpr` in the command prompt?

Comment: You might be breaking the license terms as the company who owns the license doesn't exist anymore. If you do intend to use this for work you probably should consider getting a new license.

Comment: There’s a lot of questions about this. Do you need enterprise edition? It could be the laptop came with a regular Windows 10 license before being upgraded previously. Do you need to keep all the old stuff on the laptop? It would be better to just start fresh with a Windows 10 boot disc. Bad licenses don’t prevent Windows from installing. This could be as simple as using the media creation tool to make a USB boot drive, booting it, deleting all the old partitions from the drive and installing Windows fresh. If you’re not prompted for a license during the early stages then Windows already has it

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to the question is:

> Yes you can upgrade Windows 10 Enterprise 1511 without a server

The long version is:

The 1607 iso prompted for prompted for product keys but future versions were able to take it from the running system.

1809 and 1903 both failed with the error above and the following sorts of errors in `C:\$Windows.~WS\Sources\Panther\setupact.log` and `C:\$Windows.~WS\Sources\Panther\setuperr.log`

```
2019-06-10 20:08:33, Error MOUPG CDlpTask::Cancel(986): Result = 0xC180010A
2019-06-10 20:08:33, Error MOUPG CDlpTask::Cancel(982): Result = 0xC1800104
2019-06-10 20:08:33, Error MOUPG CSetupManager::Execute(284): Result = 0x800704C7
2019-06-10 20:08:33, Error MOUPG CSetupHost::Execute(412): Result = 0x800704C7
```

However, 1909 gave a much more meaningful error message containing `Failed to backup BCD database`

This led me to https://scottiestech.info/2016/07/22/fix-something-happened-windows-10-installation-failed-errors/

From a recovery command prompt the following commands deleted and rebuilt the BCD

```
C:
cd boot
attrib -s -h -r bcd
ren C:\boot\bcd bcd.old
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

Running the 1909 iso then succeeded and I am now on Windows 10 1909 (OS Build 18363.418)